# Multithreading in groovy script

Tags: multithreading, groovy, parallel-processing

I have a producer consumer problem where i have single producer pushing into blocking queue and single consumer consuming from the queue. once a message is consumed, i am doing several operations on that batch of message. how can i parallelise the logic processing on each batch of message. below is the code snippet. also suggest if should i consider multiple consumer to do this task.

```
ThreadX = Thread.start('producer') {
//data retrieve from DB
while(row){
   queue.put(message)
  }
   queue.put("KILL")
}
ThreadY = Thread.start('Consumer') {
    while(true){
        sleep(200)
      //  print(Thread.currentThread().name)
        def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
        def var = jsonSlurper.parseText(queue.take().toString())
        if(var.getAt(0).equals("KILL"))
            return
        var.each { fileExists(it) } // **need  parallelize this part**
    }

boolean fileExists(key){
    if(key) {
    //some logic
        sleep 1000
    }
}
}
```

Update: tried following code but it somehow only process 1st batch of 10 message consumed by consumer

```
ExecutorService exeSvc = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5)

ThreadY = Thread.start('Consumer') {
    while(true){
        sleep(200)
      //  print(Thread.currentThread().name)
        def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
        def var = jsonSlurper.parseText(queue.take().toString())
        if(var.getAt(0).equals("KILL"))
            return
        var.each { exeSvc.execute({-> fileExists(it)
            sleep(200)
        }) }
    }
}
```

please help

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in the line `var.each { exeSvc.execute({-> fileExists(it)` where the implicit variable `it` from the outer closure is used within an inner closure. Should be something like `var.each { fileName -> exeSvc.execute { fileExists(filName)`. Other than that, I just added some logs for troubleshooting and to confirm the execution flow. Working version of the script below:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService
import java.util.concurrent.Executors
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

Queue queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<String>()
def messages = [
        '["key1", "key2", "key3", "key4", "key5"]',
        '["key6", "key7", "key8", "key9", "key10"]',
        '["key11", "key12", "key13", "key14", "key15"]',
        '["key16", "key17", "key18", "key19", "key20"]',
        '["key21", "key22", "key23", "key24", "key25"]',
]

Thread.start('producer') {
    messages.each { message ->
        println("Producing message $message")
        queue.put(message)
    }
    queue.put('KILL')
}

ExecutorService exeSvc = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5)
def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()

Thread.start('Consumer') {
    while (true) {
        sleep(200)

        String message = queue.take()
        println("Consumed message $message")
        if (message == 'KILL') {
            exeSvc.shutdown()
            exeSvc.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            return
        }

        def var = jsonSlurper.parseText(message)
        var.each { fileName ->
            exeSvc.execute {
                fileExists(fileName)
                sleep(200)
            }
        }
    }
}

boolean fileExists(key) {
    println("Key: $key")
    if (key) {
        sleep 1000
    }
}
```